# Get a relationship between position vector return by getposition method in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I wrote a code for image cropping. I used imrect to draw a rectangle on the image and then get the position of it by using the method getposition. I wrote a function which uses image pixel coordinates for cropping operation. **How can I create a relationship between values return by getposition method and image pixel coordinates**.My code for cropping is as follows,

```
 [rnum cnum dim]=size(img);
    for h=1:dim
        for i=1:width
            for j=1:height
                negative(i,j,h)=img(xmin+i,ymin+j,h);
            end
        end
    end
```

width,height,xmin,ymin have to found from getposition method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, `imrect`'s `getPosition` method will return:

```
 [xmin ymin width height] = getPosition( h );
```

The first two values are the top-left corner of the rectangle, and the next two values are the length of the sides of the rectangle. These should all be in pixel coordinates if you are using `imrect`.

To crop an image based on these position values, you will start at the top-left corner of `(xmin, ymin)` and go to the bottom-right corner at `(xmin+width-1, ymin+height-1)`.

You should not use `for` loops to get the pixel data, you can take advantage of MATLAB's vectorization characteristics and do the following:

```
CroppedImageMatrix = OriginalImageMatrix( [ymin : 1 : ymin+height-1],
                                          [xmin : 1 : xmin+width-1],
                                          : );
```

This will immediately "crop" the image and place the cropped data into the new matrix. You can do this because you are using a rectangular crop and all of the indices correspond to create a rectangular lattice of points. It would be "trickier" if this was not a rectangular crop.

This also will work the same for color or grayscale images because you do not need to index the channel dimension, you just take the values from every available channel.

P.S. - Documentation page for `imrect`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html

Comment: Thanks :) I get float values for xmin and ymin. So I wonder whether they actually pixel coordinates?

Comment: @ChamathSajeewa yes, sorry for not clarifying about that. What you get is technically a "sub-pixel" coordinate value (floating point values stored by default as `double`s). The internals of the `getPosition` method use the screen position to determine the pixel location in the image, and since the screen has a higher resolution than the displayed image, you end up with floating-point precision instead of just integer pixel locations. You can choose how to round these values to integers based on your preference, before using them as indices.

Comment: not very clear, can you explain it with a small example